# mysql statment for finding word with highest count value

Tags: mysql, database, select

How can I make a select statement that will allow me to get the distinct words with its corresponding count but the count retrieved has to be the largest value.

For context 
My table has 3 columns: word, count, url

I go through a bunch of urls and count the occurrences of each word on a page. Both the word and url columns make up a composite primary key.

[image]

Not that I will count biology twice, as long as it comes from two different links. That's why it is important I only return one occurrence of the word with its highest count. Any input appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the table structure with the values you have shown in http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select [word], max([count])
from test
group by [word]
```

Comment: Wow. That worked. Embarrassed I didn't figure that out myself. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query -

```
SELECT WORD, MAX(COUNT), URL
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY WORD
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable 
INNER JOIN (SELECT word, MAX(count) AS maxCount FROM YourTable GROUP BY word) t 
ON t.maxCount = YourTable.count AND t.word = Yourtable.word
```